RAM size devides by 2
I have home physical server for nextcloud, some sites, etc.
I build it 2 years ago and only recently noticed that instead of 16GB, only 8 are displayed and working. Used this command for check: wget -qO- bench.sh | bash
At the same time, there are 16 physically. I thought it was a broken RAM (amd radeon), so today I bought a new 32 GB kingston. And that's what I see:

So I decided to change slots (was 2 4, now 1 3) and it still the same. Found this command:
sudo dmidecode --type 17

And it says that system can see 32 gb. What should I do to fix it? I have 64bit system:

Result of dmidecode:
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0009
        Error Information Handle: 0x000F
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 254F4E2E
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KHX2666C13/16GX
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0009
        Error Information Handle: 0x0012
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: Unknown
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Unknown
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0009
        Error Information Handle: 0x0014
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 254F529A
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: KHX2666C13/16GX
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0009
        Error Information Handle: 0x0017
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: Unknown
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Unknown
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None


-> https://superuser.com/

While this is perhaps borderline on topic here, so I don't want to migrate it myself, I think @ArtemS.Tashkinov is right and you are more likely to get useful answers on [su]. I suggest you delete this and just post there instead.
